# How to perform tree shaking for lodash in a create-react-app project?

Tags: reactjs, lodash, create-react-app, tree-shaking, react-app-rewired

I need to perform tree-shaking to reduce bundle sizes where lodash and some other libraries are being used.
I've converted all lodash imports like this:
`import {isEmpty} from "lodash";`
But still bundle size is not getting reduced.

To use plugins like '`lodash-webpack-plugin`', we need to configure in `webpack.config.js`, which is not possible in a create-react-app project. I tried using `react-app-rewired` but getting issues like:
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GtN0.png)

Following versions are being used in the project:

1. react-scripts: 3.4.1
2. webpack: 4.42.0
3. react: 16.13.1
4. lodash: 4.17.15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Webpack can perform tree shaking automatically when ES6 modules(import/export syntax) are used.

Looks like lodash is built to use Common-JS modules.

So you can use single export and cherry-pick methods to reduce size of bundle:

```
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty";
```

With this import, only isEmpty function will be included in your bundle.

Alternatively, you can try to use [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) written in ES6